# How to show newsletters lists options in the mailchimp free form?

Tags: 7, emails

When I try to create a list on my drupal site, i should only select one list from the mailchimp list dropdown so the user should subscribe to that list only using hte mailchimp free form.

But I want that user should select the list using the mailchimp free form to which list he wants to subscribe?

Is it possible? How will I do that?

Comment: Define interest groups within the same list from mailchimp site

Comment: I  have two lists. And for both lists I have checked the option of "show it on registration page". So on the registration page I have the option of selecting a list  . So same thing I want in a block for anonymous user.

Comment: http://mzlizz.mit.edu/s1l-drupal-mailchimp-module-configuration-tutorial 
Please follow above link . Hope it helps :)

Comment: This tutorial does not have the solution form my question.

Comment: Well then please follow Mailchimp Api examples from mailchimp site itself.